# What's the formal term for a function that can be written in terms of `fold`?

Tags: linq, function, math, language-agnostic, functional-programming

I use the LINQ [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) operator quite often. Essentially, it lets you "accumulate" a function over a sequence by repeatedly applying the function on the last computed value of the function and the next element of the sequence.

For example:

```
int[] numbers = ...
int result = numbers.Aggregate(0, (result, next) => result + next * next);
```

will compute the sum of the squares of the elements of an array.

After some googling, I discovered that the general term for this in functional programming is ["fold"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29). This got me curious about functions that could be written as folds. In other words, the `f` in `f = fold op`.

I think that a function that can be computed with this operator only needs to satisfy (please correct me if I am wrong):

```
f(x1, x2, ..., xn) = f(f(x1, x2, ..., xn-1), xn)
```

This property seems common enough to deserve a special name. Is there one?

Comment: A mathematical function usually has a fixed number of arguments. It is not clear what is meant by +(1,2,3,4,5), unless you *define* it as 1+2+3+4+5.

Comment: @n.m.: Yes, that's something I've thought about. Is there really no concept of a "variadic function" in mathematics? How about in the context of ["Finite sequences and series"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29#Basic_Properties)?

Comment: You can define a "variadic" function, but you usually do it in terms of more simple functions. In any case, when reason about a fold, you think in terms in two-argument functions, not variadic ones. You can fold a (+), the properties of this fold are determined by properties of the two-argument (+) alone. Moreover, if you define a variadic (+) function, you basically must **define it as** the fold of the two-argument (+). So it is not productive to think about variadic functions in this context.

Comment: Are you familiar with [associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative) and [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative) functions?  With both properties, you can think of `f(x1,...,xn)` as a function from the unordered set `{x1,...,xn}` to the aggregated value.

Comment: @han: Yes, I certainly see how associativity is related, but there is no requirement of commutativity.

Comment: Also you can think about [Monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) which denotes associative property of functions like (+) and (*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify the question: 'sum of squares' is a special function because it has the property that it can be expressed in terms of the fold functional plus a lambda, ie

```
sumSq = fold ((result, next) => result + next * next) 0
```

Which functions `f` have this property, where `dom f = { A tuples }`, `ran f :: B`?

Clearly, due to the mechanics of fold, the statement that f is foldable is the assertion that there exists an `h :: A * B -> B` such that for any n > 0, x1, ..., xn in A, `f ((x1,...xn)) = h (xn, f ((x1,...,xn-1)))`.

The assertion that the `h` exists says almost the same thing as your condition that

```
f((x1, x2, ..., xn)) = f((f((x1, x2, ..., xn-1)), xn))     (*)
```

so you were very nearly correct; the difference is that you are requiring `A=B` which is a bit more restrictive than being a general fold-expressible function. More problematically though, fold in general also takes a starting value `a`, which is set to `a = f nil`. The main reason your formulation (*) is wrong is that it assumes that h is whatever f does on pair lists, but that is only true when `h(x, a) = a`. That is, in your example of sum of squares, the starting value you gave to Accumulate was 0, which is a does-nothing when you add it, but there are fold-expressible functions where the starting value does something, in which case we have a fold-expressible function which does not satisfy (*).

For example, take this fold-expressible function `lengthPlusOne`:

```
lengthPlusOne = fold  ((result, next) => result + 1) 1
```

`f (1) = 2`, but `f(f(), 1) = f(1, 1) = 3`.

Finally, let's give an example of a functions on lists not expressible in terms of fold. Suppose we had a black box function and tested it on these inputs:

```
f (1) = 1
f (1, 1) = 1    (1)
f (2, 1) = 1
f (1, 2, 1) = 2 (2)
```

Such a function on tuples (=finite lists) obviously exists (we can just define it to have those outputs above and be zero on any other lists). Yet, it is not foldable because (1) implies `h(1,1)=1`, while (2) implies `h(1,1)=2`.

I don't know if there is other terminology than just saying 'a function expressible as a fold'. Perhaps a (left/right) context-free list function would be a good way of describing it?

Answer (score 4):

An [Iterated binary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_binary_operation) may be what you are looking for.

You would also need to add some stopping conditions like

```
f(x) = something
f(x1,x2) = something2
```

They define a binary operation `f` and another function `F` in the link I provided to handle what happens when you get down to `f(x1,x2)`.

Comment: +1 Good answer. There are lots of ways of thinking about fold; in these terms we're saying that the fold-expressible functions are 'iterable'. I wrote a note in my answer about those stopping conditions.

Answer (score 3):

In functional programming, `fold` is used to aggregate results on collections like list, array, sequence... Your formulation of `fold` is incorrect, which leads to confusion. A correct formulation could be:

```
fold f e [x1, x2, x3,..., xn] = f((...f(f(f(e, x1),x2),x3)...), xn)
```

The requirement for `f` is actually very loose. Lets say the type of elements is `T` and type of e is `U`. So function `f` indeed takes two arguments, the first one of type `U` and the second one of type `T`, and returns a value of type `U` (because this value will be supplied as the first argument of function `f` again). In short, we have an "accumulate" function with a signature `f: U * T -> U`. **Due to this reason, I don't think there is a formal term for these kinds of function.**

In your example, `e = 0`, `T = int`, `U = int` and your lambda function `(result, next) => result + next * next` has a signature`f: int * int -> int`, which satisfies the condition of "foldable" functions.

In case you want to know, another variant of `fold` is `foldBack`, which accumulates results with the reverse order from `xn` to `x1`:

```
   foldBack f [x1, x2,..., xn] e = f(x1,f(x2,...,f(n,e)...))
```

There are interesting cases with commutative functions, which satisfy f(x, y) = f(x, y), when `fold` and `foldBack` return the same result. About `fold` itself, it is a specific instance of catamorphism in category theory. You can read more about catamorphism [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism).

Comment: As I said, f only has two arguments. The nature of fold helps to apply f on the whole collection. You were confused between the inner function f and the outer function fold, which leads to a variadic function f. Maybe the following one is close to your idea: `fold f e [x1, x2, ..., xn] = f(fold f e [x1, x2, ..., xn-1], xn)`

Comment: Right, but if we allow variadic functions, my formulation is correct? Also could you explain the "Due to this reason, I don't think there is a formal term for these kinds of function" bit? I don't quite get it.

Comment: Apparently in LINQ the function must be of type `T * T -> T`.

Comment: @han: No, that isn't a requirement - I guess my example wasn't general enough to illustrate that.

Comment: I think @pad and @Ani are talking about different things, slightly. The original question is 'which functions are foldable', meaning, which functions can be written in terms of fold. pad's answer was that a foldable function is any with type `U * T -> U` is about which lambdas we can apply fold to. The original question was about the property of 'sum of squares' though that mean that it can be written as a fold plus a lambda.

Comment: PS. The dual of fold isn't foldBack; foldl and foldr are categorically the same function really, just written out with different left/right action. The dual of fold unfortunately produces infinitely large objects of kind of 'tuple mirrors', so you're not going to see it any programming language.